# cvs [checkout aborted]: client too old to checkout to /tmp/test1

Tags: cvs

Any ideas here? It usually works ifIi give it a directory name instead of path:

```
cvs -d HOST1:/repository checkout -Pd temp file.py
```

It does not work this way:

```
cvs -d HOST1:/repository checkout -Pd /tmp/test1 file.py
```

Comment: only on Red hat linux and not on solaris!

Comment: Is "client too old" an actual error message from the `cvs` commmand?